# redux: set initial state along with compose middleware

Tags: redux, redux-middleware

The normal way to set initial state (that overrides a reducer's own default initial state) while creating a store is to provide a second argument to createStore ([how to set initial state in redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823132/how-to-set-initial-state-in-redux)). But I've unfortunately cobbled together a tangle of stuff (pardon the mixed metaphor) that I don't really understand and I don't know where to put my desired initial state:

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
  )
);
```

I hope no one asks to see my combineReducers and middleware construction code 'cause that's even more embarrassing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Still use second argument:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  { your: { initial: { state: {} } } },
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
  )
);
```