# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

While learning `React` with `Redux` just trying to render some user details.

Getting the typical error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map'`. I can understand that `state.users` in the `mapStateToProps` method is `undefined`. Tried using the `constructor` to set the initial state. But no luck. Am I missing something trivial? the error is on **return this.props.users.map((user) => {**  line in **createListItems()** method.

**containers\userList.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import bindActionCreators from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class UserList extends Component{

createListItems(){
         return this.props.users.map((user) => { // here is the error
            return (
                <li key={user.id}>
                    {user.firstName} {user.lastName}
                </li>
            );
        }   );
}

render(){
    return(
        <ul>
            {this.createListItems()}
        </ul>
    );
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    users: state.users
};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

**reducers\userReducers.js**

```
export default function () {
return [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: "sally",
        lastName: "brown",
        age: 12,
        location: "lund"

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: "Terance",
        lastName: "Smith",
        age: 23,
        location: "London"

    },
    {
        id: 3,
        firstName: "Petter",
        lastName: "Phantom",
        age: 34,
        location: "Manchester"

    }
]
}
```

**reducers\index.js**

```
import  { combineReducers }  from 'redux';
import UserReducers from './userReducers';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    users: UserReducers
});

export default allReducers;
```

**src\index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/app';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { createStore }  from 'redux';
import allReducers from './reducers/userReducers'; 
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


let store = createStore(allReducers);

ReactDOM.render(
     <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
     </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Is this all the code or did you leave stuff out for brevity?  I'm not seeing where your reducer is actually setting the state in the store.

Comment: You are not dispatching any action to set your `users` state. Either preload the redux state or dispatch an action to update that state with your `users` state.

Comment: This is all the code I have so far. I haven't used any `Action` yet. Without dispatching an Action is it not possible to load the state till I start using Action?

Comment: @shaz Before action you can set initial value of redux state. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823132/how-to-set-initial-state-in-redux

Comment: @sma it's in the the src\index.js where I am passing allReducers. Actually found the issue. There was a wrong import for the variable `allReducers`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `reducer` couldn't set the state to the `store` hence `state.users` was `undefined`.

Wrong import was done for the variable **allReducers** in the **src\index.js** file.

**incorrect**

```
src\index.js
...
import allReducers from './reducers/userReducers';
```

**correct**

```
src\index.js
...
import allReducers from './reducers/index';
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest modifying the way you are building your reducers a bit, as follows:

```
// reducers/users.js

const ADD_USER = 'add.user'

const USERS = [{
  id: 1,
  firstName: "sally",
  lastName: "brown",
  age: 12,
  location: "lund"
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: "Terance",
  lastName: "Smith",
  age: 23,
  location: "London"
}, {
  id: 3,
  firstName: "Petter",
  lastName: "Phantom",
  age: 34,
  location: "Manchester"
}]

export default (state = USERS, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return [...state, action.user]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I added the `ADD_USER` bit to show why this format is valuable. It allows you to simply add in other actions, and have the state management update accordingly and automatically.

```
// store.js

import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'
import users from './reducers/users.js'

export default createStore(
  combineReducers({ users }),
  {} // Initial State
)
```

Now, your store should work correctly with the binding that you have - and you're a bit more free to begin extending it with additional actions.