# how to make React Redux application work with fixture data?

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to configure react redux application to work with dummy data (fixtures) till the time server API is ready ? Once API are ready flip the switch and it starts working on the server API for fetching data instead of dummy data(json files).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is `initialState`. When you create your Redux store you can pass an `initialState` to it. [Here are some docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/store) on `createStore`.

> You may optionally specify the initial state as the second argument to createStore().

Also here is a [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823132/how-to-set-initial-state-in-redux) similar to yours

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store some fixed data until you fetch your data to be updated is

using [Initializing State](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state)

then using React Lifecycle Method  `componentDidMount()` to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) webpage as a fake backed. It returns dummy data for REST requests. Once your real backend is ready, just change the endpoint in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**The non React-Redux part:**

You're going to want to make an api for your application.

import fakeData from './fakeData.json';

```
const api = {
    getTodos: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(fakeData.todos);
        });
    },
    ...
};
```

This way you can import the api methods into your components and use a method to access your data. This is good because now the components don't care about how the data is retrieved, just that it is accessed through that method with a certain signature.

Now you can use that method throughout your code, and when you have a backend you just change the implementation of the methods on the api object.

**The React-Redux part:**

If you would like to seed your application with state, you can do this in the `createStore` method; Which takes an optional second argument, `preloadedState`. Read about here [Initializing State](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state) in the official [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) documentation.